# Can I change my Podcast name without loosing my subscribers in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I have a Podcast. I herd that if I change the Title of it I might loose my subscribers.

Is there a way to change my Podcast Title without loosing my subscribers in iTunes?

Comment: Before we do research on this, what has your investigation turned up?  Please add it to your question.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a change to the `title` tag within your podcast's RSS feed will update the podcast title within iTunes, without losing subscribers. It may take a day or two for such a change take effect within iTunes.

---

**Note:** The main concern is that making a title change to a podcast *where the feed is created for you automatically* could ***potentially*** change the url for the feed which will stop the podcast from updating [...and an 'easy fix' for that could be resubmitting your podcast, which ***would*** lose your subscribers!].

So http://example.com/oldTitle.rss *might* become http://example.com/newTitle.rss.

**If needed**, it's possible to update the feed URL within iTunes, without resubmitting your podcast or losing subscribers, as described by Apple in the 'Changing Your RSS Podcast Feed URL' section of their [podcast specs](http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html):

> You can move your podcast feed from one location to another. To avoid
>   losing subscribers, you must announce the change directly to all users
>   who are subscribed to your feed. To do so, you should:
>
> – Use the `<itunes:new-feed-url>` tag described in the iTunes RSS Tags
>   section below.
>
> – Set your web server to return an HTTP 301 redirect
>   response when receiving a request for the old feed.
>
> This will update
>   the iTunes Store with the new feed URL and your subscribers will
>   continue to receive new episodes automatically. Be sure to maintain
>   the `<itunes:new-feed-url>` tag and the HTTP 301 redirect response for
>   at least 4 weeks to ensure that most subscribers have attempted to
>   download your most recent episode and have thereby received the new
>   URL.